# How to search for a character the displays as "<85>" in Vim

Tags: vim, ascii, newline, replace, ebcdic

I have a file that was converted from EBCDIC to ASCII. Where there used to be new lines there are now characters that show up as `<85>` (a symbol representing a single character, not the four characters it appears to be) and the whole file is on one line. I want to search for them and replace them all with new lines again, but I don't know how.

I tried putting the cursor over one and using <kbd>*</kbd> to search for the next occurrence, hoping that it might show up in my `/` search history. That didn't work, it just searched for the word that followed the `<85>` character.

I searched Google, but didn't see anything obvious.

My goal is to build a search and replace string like:

```
:%s/<85>/\n/g
```

Which currently just gives me:

```
E486: Pattern not found: <85>
```

Comment: You can press `y<Space>` to copy a single character.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found "[Find & Replace non-printable characters in vim](http://durgaprasad.wordpress.com/2007/09/25/find-replace-non-printable-characters-in-vim/)" searching Google. It seems like you should be able to do:

```
:%s/\%x85/\r/gc
```

Omit the `c` to do the replacement without prompting, try with `c` first to make sure it is doing what you want it to do.

In Vim, typing `:h \%x` gives more details.  In addition to `\%x`, you can use `\%d`, `\%o`, `\%u` and `\%U` for decimal, octal, up to four and up to eight hexadecimal characters.

Answer (score 2):

For special character searching, win1252 for example, for the case of `<80>`,`<90>`,`<9d>`...
type:

```
/\%u80, \/%u90, /\%u9d ...
```

from the editor.

Similarly for octal, decimal, hex, type: `/\%oYourCode`, `/\%dYourCode`, `/\%xYourCode`.

Answer (score -4):

try this: `:%s/<85>/^M/g`

note: press Ctrl-V together then M

or if you don't mind using another tool,

```
awk '{gsub("<85>","\n")}1' file
```

Comment: The \n isn't the problem. It's the <85>. Thanks though.

Comment: The "<85>" is a single character, not a four character string of <, 8, 5, and >.

Comment: echo '------------------------------------------------------------------------- BEGIN ----------------------------------------------------------------------- '<85>binDir=...etc, etc...